# Formal Description of Data Structures and Algorithms

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages

Math is (mostly) established on first-order formal logic. In computer science, the core study is about algorithms and data structures. I am wondering, if it is possible to describe algorithms and data structures in formal first-order logic, using object language. For example, can we see an algorithm as an object (a, say, in a formal system), and assert that there exists a time complexity function and a space complexity function associated with it. Further, can we use formal mathematical language to describe data structures such as linked lists, binary trees?

Comment: I was just thinking about this question yesterday. For example, a constructor of an OOP comes with a set of rules, almost like axioms for a function. I wonder if things become more organized and clear when these definitions are defined in terms of mathematics versus handwavy sentences that differ between person to person.

Comment: Or is it possible to give rigorous, non-open ended and non-self referential definitions to terminologies used in software engineering.

Comment: The answer is almost certainly yes, and that it has been done. Consider asking at the theoretical computer science stackexchange https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Most likely yes, but in most practical cases I know of the notation and complexity gets too unwieldy unless absolutely necessary.  eg., proving correctness of software critical to human life- space flight, some medical software, etc.

Comment: These are topics that have been intensively studied in computer science for many years. Higher-order logic tends to be more useful than first-order logic in this connection (e.g., since the natural defining properties of abstract data types like lists and trees involve induction). As suggested by Ethan Bolker, you will likely get better references and comments if you post your question on the theoretical computer science  stackexchnge forum.

Comment: @nickalh What you mentioned is why I think automated proof has to be the future. Human-driven math proof is like crafting an airplane using hammers and nails, or is like family-owned hand-made shoe shops in the era of modern industry. It has to be replaced by automated mechanism someday, or scientific discoveries will become slower and slower, as we progress into areas of more depth.